# Hall sensor or encoder

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, encoder, hall-effect

[image]I have an Ashwoods 1008-269 motor, and I'm having some trouble actually finding a proper datasheet for it. Does anyone know whether it uses encoder or hall sensor, and the pin layout of the output from the rotor.

Thanks in advance
[image]